# Twitter API upload with PHP OAuth

Tags: php, api, twitter, oauth, multipart

I've been trying to find the best OAuth PHP lib for Twitter for hours. the TmhOAuth by Matt Harris seems kinda bloated (no offence) and started shooting PHP Warnings and Strict Standards notices right after I "installed" it.

All I want is to update my bg photo through the API. Just mine, so there is no need for any login and callbacks of any kind, all the keys are hard-coded.

In the end I found out about PHP's own thing: http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php

Seemed cool because everything has 4 lines of code. The auth works and I can push stuff through the API, I just can't seem to send the image parameter though. This is the method: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/account/update_profile_background_image

I've found some examples that were using upload forms, but I have the photo already saved in a file, so how do I provide the, quote, **base64-encoded image as raw multipart data**?

```
$oauth->fetch
(
    'https://api.twitter.com/1/account/update_profile_background_image.json',
    array
    (
        'image' => '@' . $img_path . ';type=image/jpeg'
    ),
    'POST'
);
```

Doesn't work, instead I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'OAuthException' with message 'Invalid auth/bad request (got a 500, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)'

Comment: Cant you encode the data with this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php

Comment: Sorry if this comes out as stupid, but could you give me an example? Should I encode the contents of the image file, the path, or the entire parameter... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested I ended up using TmhOAuth in the end. Bloated but it did the job.

```
$image = array
(
    "@$path",
    'type=image/jpeg',
    "filename=$name"
);
$params = array
(
    'image' => implode(';', $image),
    'use' => 'true'
);

// Request

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url
(
    '1/account/update_profile_background_image'
),
$params, true, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the image like this:

```
<?php 

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('file.jpg'); 

$im_Data = base64_encode($im); 
?>
```

Then you should be able to add $img_Data into the api call.

Comment: It says "Warning: base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given."

Comment: Then set the parameter to the string that holds the location of the image. Take out imagecreatefromjpeg.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is an open issue yet but the "image" key must start with "@" too.

```
$oauth->fetch
(
    'https://api.twitter.com/1/account/update_profile_background_image.json',
    array
    (
        '@image' => '@' . $img_path . ';type=image/jpeg'
    ),
    'POST'
);
```